# Планировщик windows - завершение задания после выполнения Python win32com.client

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нашёл вот такой вот пример:

```
import datetime
import win32com.client

scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
scheduler.Connect()
root_folder = scheduler.GetFolder('\\')
task_def = scheduler.NewTask(0)

# Create trigger
start_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
TASK_TRIGGER_TIME = 1
trigger = task_def.Triggers.Create(TASK_TRIGGER_TIME)
trigger.StartBoundary = start_time.isoformat()

# Create action
TASK_ACTION_EXEC = 0
action = task_def.Actions.Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC)
action.ID = 'DO NOTHING'
action.Path = 'cmd.exe'
action.Arguments = '/c "exit"'

# Set parameters
task_def.RegistrationInfo.Description = 'Test Task'
task_def.Settings.Enabled = True
task_def.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = False

# Register task
# If task already exists, it will be updated
TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE = 6
TASK_LOGON_NONE = 0
root_folder.RegisterTaskDefinition(
    'Test Task',  # Task name
    task_def,
    TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
    '',  # No user
    '',  # No password
    TASK_LOGON_NONE)
```

Отрабатывает нормально, но мне нужно удалять задание после завершения. 
Вроде есть флаг TASK_FLAG_DELETE_WHEN_DONE , не соображу, куда его можно добавить? Если он вообще подходит в данной ситуации -  тестирую на Windows 7, в свойствах созданного задания есть  пункт "Если повтор задачи не запланирован, удалять через [немедленно, 30дн, 90дн, 180 дн, 365дн]".
Python 3.6.8